# dd: writing '/dev/null': No space left on device

Tags: linux, shell, kernel, filesystems, dd

I am reading a 550MB file into /dev/null and I am getting

```
dd: writing '/dev/null': No space left on device
```

I was surprised. I thought /dev/null is a black hole where you can send as much as you want ( because its a virtual fs).

Yes my disk is almost full when I get this error. What can I do other than deleting content from the disk?

```
 ls -l /dev/null
 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 July 7 21:58 /dev/null
```

Instead of

```
 crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        1,   3 July 7 02:58 /dev/null
```

Command I am using:

```
time sh -c "dd if=$filename of=/dev/null"
```

Comment: can you provide the output of `ls -l /dev/null`

Comment: @Patrick added ls -l

Comment: Could you also copy/paste the dd command you're executing?

Comment: @forcefsck Done, added the command

Comment: what happens if you use `time dd if="$filename" of=/dev/null`? BTW. dd also outputs time elapsed.

Comment: This is indeed weird. Writing to `/dev/null` should never trigger this error, since it doesn't actually write anything anywhere. Do you get the same effect without `time`? Please post the output of `strace dd if=$filename of=/dev/null` (do it with a **file containing no confidential information**), or of `strace dd if=$filename of=/dev/null` if `time` is needed to trigger the error.

Comment: @Gilles Problem was that my /dev/null was not a character special file. I updated my question above.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`/dev/null` is a special file, of type character device. The driver for that character device ignores whatever you try to write to the device and writes are always successful. If a write to `/dev/null` fails, it means that you've somehow managed to remove the proper `/dev/null` and replace it by a regular file. You might have accidentally removed `/dev/null`; then the next `… >/dev/null` would have recreated it as a regular file.

Run `ls -l /dev/null` and check that the line looks something like

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 3 Sep 13  2011 /dev/null
```

It must begin with `crw-rw-rw-`: `c` for a character device, and permissions that allow everyone to read and write. The file should be owned by root, though it isn't very important. The two numbers after the owner and group identify the device ([major and minor device number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#Implementation)). Above I show the values under Linux; different unix variants have different values. The date is typically either the date when the system was installed or the date of the last reboot and doesn't matter.

If you need to recreate the file, some systems provide a `MAKEDEV` commmands, either in root's PATH or in `/dev`. Run `cd /dev; ./MAKEDEV std` or something like this to recreate the standard basic devices such as `/dev/null`. Or create the device manually, supplying the correct device numbers; on Linux, that's

```
mknod -m 666 /dev/null c 1 3
```

Comment: Wow! you're a lifesaver. Thanks, this really helps. I never deleted null but it wasn't there,  i created one manually.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr You probably have a script running as root that removes `/dev/null` in some circumstances, perhaps something like `tmp_file=$(mktemp); … … … if [ "$mode" = "quiet" ]; then tmp_file=/dev/null; done; … … … rm "$tmp_file"`

Comment: I'll have to check my scripts then,  if this is true,  there is a chance that null will be deleted again.  I'll come back if i'm unable to locate(solve) this situation.  Thanks for the heads up. Cheers!! :)